# RedirectMatch issue (redirecting folder, but not contents inside folder)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have tried this every which way I could, but am not getting any love.  I am attempting to redirect a subfolder in the site to just a static page.  But I do NOT want to redirect anything ELSE that is inside said folder.

I have tried using the regular redirect 301, but of course that redirects everything in the subfolder.

To sum up:  I want to redirect `http://www.domain.com/folder/`  to `http://www.domain.com/foldername2/file.php` without redirecting anything else inside `/folder/`.

The following is what I have in my htaccess... but... it is just ignoring it completely.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder$ http://www.domain.com/foldername2/file.php
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on HTTP, you can use a nearly empty index.html file which contains a `<meta>` refresh tag in the head section of the document.

The wikipedia article on [meta refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) has some good examples, e.g.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">
```

The `0` means "zero seconds"—that is, immediately.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however, this is not a SEO friendly way of doing it.  It needs to be a solid 301.  Furthermore, the index.php file inside the /folder/ "controls" other files inside the folder by having variables passed to it, which is why i only want to redirect the /folder/.

Answer (score 0):

After much struggling, I found the answer!  It does not use the RedirectMatch, however. It uses a rewrite condition and rule instead.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/foldername2/file.php [L,R=301]
```